# How to work with types from monorepo in another project

Tags: javascript, typescript, monorepo

I have a monorepo project which consist of 3 packages. Monorepo structure looks like this:

```
- packages/
  - common/
    - types.ts
  - ComponentA/
  - ComponentB/
```

As you can see, in common package I have one file which contains all types (some of them are shared) for both components.
When I'm building e.g. `ComponentA` using Babel and Webpack, at the end all types are emitted in one single file `main.d.ts` which look like this:

```
declare module "common/types" {
    export type Foo = {
        width: number;
        height: number;
    };
}

declare module "ComponentA/src/main" {
    export * from "common/types";
}
...
```

In in `main.js` file of `ComponentA` I'm also exporting all types and `types` are specified in `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "ComponentA",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/main.js",
  "types": "dist/main.d.ts",
  "license": "MIT",
  "files": [
    "dist/*"
  ],
...
}
```

Problem is, that when I wanna use types of `ComponentA` (e.g. type `Foo`) in another typescript based project, types are recognized in two modules like this:

```
import 'Foo' from 'common/types'
and
import 'Foo' from 'ComponentA/src/main'
```

I know that type `Foo` is declared in `common/module` in generated `main.d.ts` file but naming 'common/types` doesn't make much sense. How can I improve this? Thanks

Comment: what did you find so far?